# How to force d3's date axis to draw ticks for first and last months that are not full [FIDDLE UPDATED]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, d3.js, underscore.js

I have a set of dates and values that span 13 months. First date is on Dec 31, 2011 and last is Feb 14 2013.

[image]

I need to force d3 to draw first tick as December instead of January,and, preferably, last tick as Mach. 
How should I approach this? I tried ajusting d3 range by flooring it's Min date value:

```
var domainXMin = d3.min(dataset, function(d){ return d.x; });
var domainXMax = d3.max(dataset, function(d){ return d.x; });

var domainYMin = d3.min(dataset, function(d){ return d.y; });
var domainYMax = d3.max(dataset, function(d){ return d.y; });


var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([d3.time.month.floor(domainXMin), domainXMax])
    .range([0, width]);
```

but that doesn't seem to always work. Is there even a way?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc3Lrsa1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [tickFormat](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat):

```
var monthFormat = d3.time.format("%B");
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(6)
    .innerTickSize(-height)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10)
    .tickFormat(monthFormat);
```

---

You'll probably have to resort to setting your ticks yourself:

```
.tickValues([
    new Date(2011, 11, 1),new Date(2012, 1, 1),
    new Date(2012, 3, 1),new Date(2012, 5, 1),
    new Date(2012, 7, 1),new Date(2012, 9, 1),
    new Date(2012, 11, 1),new Date(2013, 1, 1)
    ]);
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc3Lrsa1/2/).

Comment: i want December tick to show first, since there's data in December

Comment: could you explain the .domain([domainXMin - (2.628e+9 * 2), domainXMax]) part?

Comment: also. i missspoke. Last tick should be March since the last value is in March

Comment: @nuway the `domainXMin - (2.628e+9 * 2)` is just for padding.  It's the min date minus 2 months (in milliseconds), I did it so the word "December" would fit on the axis.